# Filtering with foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have three tables `tblClients`, `tblClientsActivities` and `tblActivities`

`tblClients` and `tblClientsActivities` are joined together to produce Table A below

```
SELECT * from tblClientsActivities 
left join tblclients on tblClientsActivities.fk_cid=tblclients.pk_cid

PK_AID      FK_CID     FK_AID
1             4          1   
2             4          2
3             4          4
4             5          1
5             5          3
6             5          5
7             6          1
8             6          2
9             7          6
10            8          3
```

The problem is how do i remove all clients where FK_AID <> 1

Comment: Can you provide a table with your expected result based on this very same example?

Comment: Do PK_AID an FK_AID live in tblClientsActivities or tblclients?  You mention tblActivities but don't reference it.  The two answers below will probably work, but it seems to me you should have already known that.

Answer (score 0):

#### Description

Simple use a `WHERE` clause.

#### Sample

```
SELECT * FROM tblClientsActivities 
LEFT JOIN tblclients on tblClientsActivities.fk_cid=tblclients.pk_cid
WHERE FK_AID <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

With a restriction used in a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * from tblClientsActivities
left join tblclients on tblClientsActivities.fk_cid=tblclients.pk_cid
where FK_AID != 1
```